# Multidimensional array causing error Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in PHPunit 5.7 laravel 5.6

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm pretty stuck on this bug, pretty much this is the code that runs fine

```php
$data = ['tipo'=>1];

      $respuesta = $this->json('POST','api/endpoint',$data);

      $respuesta->assertJsonFragment(['success' => 1]);
```

and this is the one that gives error Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL

```php
$data = ['data' => ['tipo'=>1]];

      $respuesta = $this->json('POST','api/endpoint',$data);

      $respuesta->assertJsonFragment(['success' => 1]);
```

The first one runs perfectly, marking the assertion, the second one, throws that error, now,ive tried, using post(), to no avail, exact same thing happens, so im lost, i dont see how a multidimensional array could do this, and while this specific api doesnt use multidimensional arrays i have many others that do

Full trace

```
Fatal error: Default value for parameters with a class type hint can only be NULL in C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\symfony\yaml\Yaml.php on line 52

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not instantiable.' in C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:895
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(735): Illuminate\Container\Container->notInstantiable('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#1 C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(608): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#2 C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(575): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#3 C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(728): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\\Cont...')
#4 C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleEx in C:\laragon\www\gerinpro2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php on line 895
```

Comment: "this specific api doesnt use multidimensional arrays" so why are you passing it one? why not pass it `$data['data']` which is the same as what you use in the first, working, call?

Comment: What does the route config look like and what is the method signature, i.e. what arguments does the called method accept, of the controller action?

Comment: Oh mostly because, i do have other apis where i need mutidimensional arrays, in fact, most of my create methods work like that, i have an array of arrays, mostly for the $data['data'] array which basically would look like this  {data => [{field1 => 1 , field 2 => 2, etc etc}]

Comment: Oh and @dbrumann route is quite simple although im not using middleware for testing so above this code i have the withoutMiddleware() method `Route::post('api/endpoint/','Roles_plan_gestionController@capturar')
->middleware('auten:---');` the method that uses arrays of arrays, accepts a structure of {'data' => [{field 1: value, field2: value }] what my controller does is on the controller it takes the "data" part of the array and runs a json_decode on it and then sends it to the corresponding method on the model, weird part is this works fine in everything else but PHPunit seems to take issue

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Of course @dbrumann, i already added it to my initial question, one more thing, i've tried to use withoutExceptionHandler(); but i guess my laravel version doesnt have it, 5.6 laravel, although ive been reading its there since 5.5, but hey who knows i get undefined method if i try and i dont think it would solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue, i was able to resolve it, it was mostly a PHP version problem, i had done a composer update command before all this, meaning my project was updated but my laravel version wasnt, in another words, those files you see in my stack trace were using features from php 7.0+ so all i had to do is change that, do the same thing but with a 5.6 php approach, which was not easy and took some time, but, Nonetheless fixed it